# changing background color in drawer - MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, styling, drawer

i cannot change backgroundColor in Drawer component. I do as I found in other refs and it is not working for me. I created two classes

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles'
import { Drawer, Typography } from '@mui/material';


const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = makeStyles({
    drawer: {
        width: drawerWidth,    
      },
      drawerPaper: {
        width: drawerWidth,
        backgroundColor: "#fcba03" 
      },
  });
```

```
export default function Sidebar() {
  const classes=useStyles()
    return (   
           <>
            <Drawer
                className={classes.drawer}
                variant="permanent"
                anchor="left"
                 classes={{paper: classes.drawerPaper},
                 {root:classes.drawerRoot}}               
            >
                <div>
                    <Typography variant='h5'> Home </Typography>
                </div>

            </Drawer>
               
            </>
    )
}
```

thanks for answer!

Answer (score 0):

You're not passing the classes in correct way. The `classes` prop expects an `object` with `keys` containing the class names from `makeStyle` hook. The correct syntax should be like

```
classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper, root: classes.drawerRoot }}
```

The updated code could be

```
import { makeStyles } from "@mui/styles";
import { Drawer, Typography } from "@mui/material";

const drawerWidth = 240;
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  drawer: {
    width: drawerWidth
  },
  drawerPaper: {
    "&&": {
      width: drawerWidth,
      backgroundColor: "#fcba03"
    }
  }
});

export default function Sidebar() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <>
      <Drawer
        className={classes.drawer}
        variant="permanent"
        anchor="left"
        classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper, root: classes.drawerRoot }}
      >
        <div>
          <Typography variant="h5"> Home </Typography>
        </div>
      </Drawer>
    </>
  );
}
```

**Note:** `&&` is added to increase the `specificity` of the applied styles to the paper.

[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]

Also, the support of `makeStyles` is going to be a [legacy](https://mui.com/styles/basics/) solution at sometime in future. If possible, you should probably look at the [newer styling option](https://mui.com/system/the-sx-prop/#main-content) provided in the mui v5.

Comment: Thank You very much!

hank you a lot! "Only the Box, Stack, Typography, and Grid components accept the system properties as props for the above reason. These components are designed to solve CSS problems, they are CSS component utilities." 

unfortunatelly this nice method does not work in the components like AppBar, Drawer etc.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this "improved" props like `p`, `px`, `my`, `bgcolor` etc are on the component listed above, but MUI expose for each of their components, a `sx` prop, that is an object that accept this kind of prop ! Also, I don't know if it could help, but you still can customize MUI components from the theme object if you want this style to be applied on all components occurences

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).